# How to autowire a service in a class if it has multiple capital letter in front in grails(2.5.6)

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

So I have a class where I need to inject a service in grails.

```
class APIPaymentCreateCommand implements CreateCommand {

    def cardTokensService 

}
```

I have tried the following pattern below but none of them seem to be injecting the service.

resources.groovy:

```
// 1
aPIPaymentCreateCommand(APIPaymentCreateCommand) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
// 2
apipaymentCreateCommand(APIPaymentCreateCommand) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
// 3
APIPaymentCreateCommand(APIPaymentCreateCommand) { bean ->
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
```

I have found the link below so I'm assuming the issue is around the class naming not being compliant with grails. Renaming the class is a last resort as it has a lot of dependency so trying to avoid that approach.

Any help or approach I should try would be greatly appreacited!

[How to autowire a service in grails (2.5.5) with multiple capital letters at front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810310/how-to-autowire-a-service-in-grails-2-5-5-with-multiple-capital-letters-at-fro)

Comment: Is there a bean in your context named `cardTokensService`?

Comment: there is. I am able to get the service in the class through the below code but wanted to fllow existing pattern that we currently use in the codebase instead.

def cardTokensService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('cardTokensService')

Comment: I have tried all of the bean names that you mention in the question ('aPIPaymentCreateCommand', 'apipaymentCreateCommand' and 'APIPaymentCreateCommand') and DI seems to work for all of those beans.

Comment: How are you getting a reference to the `APIPaymentCreateCommand` instance that has not been autowired?

Answer (score 1):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/kennanwhoserviceinjection.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/kennanwhoserviceinjection/blob/188f64d7fff55a24c466c17c26763e3f489d0774/grails-app/services/kennanwhoserviceinjection/CardTokensService.groovy

```
package kennanwhoserviceinjection

class CardTokensService {

    int getTheAnswer() {
        42
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/kennanwhoserviceinjection/blob/188f64d7fff55a24c466c17c26763e3f489d0774/src/groovy/kennanwhoserviceinjection/APIPaymentCreateCommand.groovy

```
package kennanwhoserviceinjection

class APIPaymentCreateCommand {
    def cardTokensService

    int getTheAnswer() {
        cardTokensService.theAnswer
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/kennanwhoserviceinjection/blob/188f64d7fff55a24c466c17c26763e3f489d0774/grails-app/controllers/kennanwhoserviceinjection/DemoController.groovy

```
package kennanwhoserviceinjection

class DemoController {

    APIPaymentCreateCommand aPIPaymentCreateCommand

    def index() {
        int answer = aPIPaymentCreateCommand.theAnswer
        render "The answer is $answer"
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/kennanwhoserviceinjection/blob/398a46efe373b5f2bafbdbbb9c25f017f9be244e/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
import kennanwhoserviceinjection.APIPaymentCreateCommand

beans = {
    aPIPaymentCreateCommand(APIPaymentCreateCommand) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }
}
```

That all works.  I used the first of your example bean definitions from `resources.groovy` but the others would work too (assuming the bean name was kept in sync in `DemoController.groovy`).